# Enable client CPU for webapp's data intensive operation

Tags: node.js, web-applications, cpu-usage

I am making a simple web app for electrical circuit simulation for study purpose.
But running it on the server and sending the result continuously to the client 
is pretty data and network intensive. Instead of that I want to use the client CPU/GPU
for doing those calculation. (Also there is nothing secretive about the algorithm I will be using. Webapp is just an interface to make the usage easier.)
Is there any provision for doing that if I use Nodejs as the back end language?
I am ok if I need to ask the user for permission to do that.
Only if the user allows we start running the simulation. (Should support Firefox , Chrome , Edge)

Comment: Node runs on the server. But you can very well send any script to your client's browser (along with the HTML they consult), make it compute whatever you have to compute, and send the result back to the server.

Comment: @JeremyThille: I was exploring the net regarding the solution to this. Found out there is one website https://everycircuit.com/ which does exactly what I wanted to do. But it says it needs "chrome://flags/#enable-nacl"  ---> Native Client
Support Native Client for all web applications, even those that were not installed from the Chrome Web Store. – Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS, Android. Could you please explain me why the enable-nacl is needed if the method you said works?

Comment: Ah, I don't know. I've never heard of NACL before